# How to get a consistent .Count / .Length property for C# generic collections?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

`List<T>` has the  `.Count` property, where as `T<>` arrays `.Length` instead. I presume this is because arrays are fixed-length whereas the others aren't, but the difference in syntax can still be frustrating.

If you refactor from an array to list, it therefore gives "does not contain a definition for .Length" errors, and it seems a waste of time having to change it when `.Count` and `.Length` are essentially the same.

Is it there a good way to deal with this ? Is it possible to extend `List<T>` to add an `.Length` property that's an alias for `.Count` for instance, and vice-versa for the generic array ? And would this be a bad idea for any reason ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx) method provided by LINQ.

This is optimised to use the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3kzhec.aspx) property provided by the [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) interface where possible (or the non-generic [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) interface too in .NET 4). So arrays, `List<T>` etc will all be optimised.

```
var yourList = new List<string> { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox" };
int count1 = yourList.Count();  // uses the ICollection<T>.Count property

var yourArray = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };
int count2 = yourArray.Count();  // uses the ICollection<T>.Count property

var yourEnumerable = yourArray.Where(x => x > 42);
int count3 = yourEnumerable.Count();  // no optimisation, iterates the sequence
```

Alternatively, if you wanted a consistent count property of some kind without running the risk of iterating an entire sequence in the non-optimised case then you could create your own extension methods. (I personally wouldn't go down this route.)

```
int count4 = yourList.GetCount();  // uses the ICollection<T>.Count property
int count5 = yourArray.GetCount();  // uses the ICollection<T>.Count property
int count6 = yourEnumerable.GetCount();  // compile-time error

// ...

public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static int GetCount<T>(this ICollection<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return source.Count;
    }

    public static int GetCount(this ICollection source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return source.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, any collection that implements the non-generic `ICollection`. And it should be noted that arrays implement both interfaces, so they gain the benefit of the shortcut logic.

Comment: Doesn't this have performance problems pre .NET 4 ? I thought it looped through (even without a predicate), and so was potentially substantially slower. Just doing a google "linq count slow" gives quite a few exmpales. Sounds like it would be the solution for .Net 4 though with the optimisations.

Comment: @mikel: Not that I'm aware of. It didn't optimise for the non-generic `ICollection` until .NET 4, but I'd imagine it would be relatively unusual for a collection to implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>`, the non-generic `ICollection` but *not* the generic `ICollection<T>`, which is what would be required for the new `ICollection` optimisation to take effect where the standard `ICollection<T>` optimisation wouldn't. (Of course the `Count` method will always be slightly slower than using any underlying `Count` property directly, but nothing that you'd notice in general day-to-day use.)

Comment: But the OP asks why a `List` does not contain the `Length` property.. `Count`does the same thing but `Length` has an O(1) time complecity

Answer (score 3):

You could put your array in a variable of type `IList<T>`.  (arrays implement this interface)

You can then use the array exactly the way you use any other `IList<T>` (although `Add` and `Remove` will throw exceptions, since arrays are fixed-length)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.Count()` method for both List and Arrays.

The `.Count()` method runs if it is available, then it falls back to the traditional `.Length`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply extend the generic List and add a count method, however if the reason for this is simply because your re-factoring and don't want to update to Count, I don't advise doing so. No need to extend a class if you're not really adding anything to it. Why not just update your code to use Count instead of Length?